# Trying to parse XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

```
    <list name="List2" refQuery="Query1" showColumnTitles="hide">
                                                <listColumns>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <contents/>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <list name="List3" refQuery="Query1" showColumnTitles="hide">
                                                                    <listColumns>
                                                                        <listColumn>
                                                                            <listColumnTitle>
                                                                                <contents/>
                                                                            </listColumnTitle>
                                                                            <listColumnBody>
                                                                                <contents>
                                                                                    <list name="List4" refQuery="Query1">
                                                                                        <style>
                                                                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                                        </style>
                                                                                        <listColumns>
                                                                                            <listColumn>
                                                                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Product type1"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Product type1"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnBody>
                                                                                            </listColumn>
                                                                                            <listColumn>
                                                                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Product name"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Product name"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnBody>
                                                                                            </listColumn>
                                                                                            <listColumn>
                                                                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Margin"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                                                                    <contents>
                                                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Margin"/>
                                                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                                                    </contents>
                                                                                                    <style>
                                                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                                                    </style>
                                                                                                </listColumnBody>
                                                                                            </listColumn>
                                                                                        </listColumns>
                                                                                    </list>
                                                                                </contents>
                                                                                <style>
                                                                                    <defaultStyles>
                                                                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="sb"/>
                                                                                    </defaultStyles>
                                                                                </style>
                                                                            </listColumnBody>
                                                                        </listColumn>
                                                                    </listColumns>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%"/>
                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="sc"/>
                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                    </style>
</list>
```

I am trying to retrieve ***refDataItem*** of  ***dataItemLabel***.
I can  retrieve it  but it come 3 times because i am retrieving the nodeList of ***listColumns*** as follows :

```
nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("listColumns");
            getListColumnsNodes(nodeList);
```

Problem is it retrieves 3 times ***listColumns*** and hence displays refDataItem of ***dataItemLabel*** 3 times, but I need it only once.

can anyone help me how to retrive it only once ?

Comment: This is not a valid XML, some tags are not closed.

Comment: If there are, in your xml, 3 times dataItemLabel, then you will receive 3 times dataItemLabel... !

Comment: Please reformat your XML; one has to scroll left and right anything of it.

Comment: This is a valid XML. I have shown some tags from it in which I was facing difficulty.

This is the input Cognos file for my program to convert to SSRS file as output. I Cannot alter the input XML file

Answer (score 0):

*nodeList[0]* is the first element in the array *nodeList*. To refer to the first element of the array use:

```
getListColumnsNodes(nodeList[0]);
```

Another way is to use unique elemement id:

```
<listColumns id="foo">
nodeList = document.getElementById("foo");
```

Here's some information about using arrays and fetching elements:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: I cannot do so....because I am getting all this as an input file and for every file there may be a different scenario.
Also I even cannot alter the input file...I need some generic Solution.. thanks though...

Comment: So use that "getListColumnsNodes(nodeList[0]);" to refer to the first element with a matching tag?

Comment: Doing so, only one value gets printed.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted when you said "retrive it only once".